# iOS : How to link a mainViewController.XIB to another page called about.XIB with a button to press?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios5, ipad-2

I have my iPad ViewController.xib with a button called about us. How to link that button to another page called about us. I have created one XIB file called about.xib. And how do i link that page. Also can I link back to the main viewController. Do i need to create another m or h files?

I have done this code but it doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction) About {
    UIViewController * about = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"About" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:about animated:YES];
    [about release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIViewController * about = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"About" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:about animated:YES];
[about release];
```

Comment: When i replace your code. I have this problem : int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); Program received signal. Its already being release [about release]. Any solution?

Comment: Try to remove [about release] and see what happen

Comment: When I press about button, it is successfully linked to XIB but when I press return it quits. Where should I put the release memory thing? I always get this error int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); Program received signal.

Comment: To dismiss the modal controller write [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] it works. The release is in the right point, after you present the controller.

Comment: Can you tell me where should I put the [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]. Is it on the 2nd viewController or the main ViewController. My program still quits during the 2nd viewController when I press return

Comment: Here is my return button - (IBAction)btnReturn {
    
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
}

Comment: One more thing, how to set my 2nd viewController to fix to landscape same as main viewController when I press next button.

Comment: In your return method remove [self.view removeFromSuperview] : this method is used when you add a subview using [self.view addSubview:myView] and it's different from [self presentModalViewController:about animated:YES]. Use only [self dismissModalViewController:YES]. Your 2nd question : in the controller which appears pressing next button use the method - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; //or other orientation. If return YES it supports all orientations
}

Comment: Can you help me at this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455576/ios-how-to-reference-a-music-background-from-a-singleton-class/8455595#8455595)